# A2C Model not making predictions/not learning after one episode

Tags: python, tensorflow, validation, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

The model we use is A2C provided by stable_baselines3, in training it works fine and learns over time but in the validation process, no predictions are being made, the model gains no rewards, and the actions are the same throughout. Is there any error in my code or logic?

```
 @staticmethod

def train_model(model, model_name, tb_log_name, SL_mode, TRAINED_MODEL_DIR, total_timesteps=5000):
        model = model.learn(
            total_timesteps=total_timesteps,
            tb_log_name=tb_log_name,
            callback=TensorboardCallback()
        )
        model.save(
            f"{TRAINED_MODEL_DIR}/{model_name.upper()}_{SL_mode}"
        )
        return model

    def DRL_validation(self, model, test_data, test_env, test_obs):
        """validation process"""
        for _ in range(len(test_data.index.unique())):
            action, _states = model.predict(test_obs, deterministic=True)
            test_obs, rewards, dones, info = test_env.step(action)

    train = data_split(
                self.df,
                start=self.train_period[0],
                end=self.train_period[1],
        )
        print(f"Train {self.df.tic[0]}")
        print(train)
            
        self.train_env = DummyVecEnv(
                [
                    lambda: self.env(
                        df=train,
                        stock_dim=self.stock_dim,
                        hmax=self.hmax,
                        initial_amount=self.initial_amount,
                        num_stock_shares=[0] * self.stock_dim,
                        buy_cost_pct=[self.buy_cost_pct] * self.stock_dim,
                        sell_cost_pct=[self.sell_cost_pct] * self.stock_dim,
                        reward_scaling=self.reward_scaling,
                        state_space=self.state_space,
                        action_space=self.action_space,
                        tech_indicator_list=self.tech_indicator_list,
                        print_verbosity=self.print_verbosity,
                        SL_pc=self.SL_pc,
                        SL_mode=self.SL_mode,
                        DD_threshold=self.DD_threshold,
                        RESULTS_DIR=self.RESULTS_DIR,
                    )
                ]
            )

        validation = data_split(
                self.df,
                start = validation_start_date,
                end = validation_end_date,
        )
        print("Valid")
        print(validation)
            
            ############## Environment Setup ends ##############

            ############## Training and Validation starts #############
            
        print("======A2C Training========")
        model_a2c = self.get_model(
                "a2c", self.train_env, self.MODELS, self.NOISE, self.TENSORBOARD_LOG_DIR, policy="MlpPolicy", model_kwargs=A2C_model_kwargs
        )
        trained_model_a2c = self.train_model(
                model_a2c,
                "a2c",
                tb_log_name=f"a2c_{0}",
                SL_mode=self.SL_mode,
                TRAINED_MODEL_DIR=self.MODEL_DIR,
                total_timesteps=timesteps_dict["a2c"],
        )  # 100_000

        print(
                "======A2C Validation from: ",
                validation_start_date,
                "to ",
                validation_end_date,
        )
        val_env_a2c = DummyVecEnv(
                [
                    lambda: self.env(
                        df=validation,
                        stock_dim=self.stock_dim,
                        hmax=self.hmax,
                        initial_amount=self.initial_amount,
                        num_stock_shares=[0] * (self.stock_dim),
                        buy_cost_pct=[self.buy_cost_pct] * (self.stock_dim),
                        sell_cost_pct=[self.sell_cost_pct] * (self.stock_dim),
                        reward_scaling=self.reward_scaling,
                        state_space=self.val_state_space,
                        action_space=self.val_action_space,
                        tech_indicator_list=self.tech_indicator_list,
                        iteration=0,
                        model_name="A2C",
                        mode="validation",
                        print_verbosity=self.print_verbosity,
                        SL_pc=self.SL_pc,
                        SL_mode=self.SL_mode,
                        DD_threshold=self.DD_threshold,
                        RESULTS_DIR=self.RESULTS_DIR,
                    )
                ]
        )
        val_obs_a2c = val_env_a2c.reset()
        self.DRL_validation(
                model=trained_model_a2c,
                test_data=validation,
                test_env=val_env_a2c,
                test_obs=val_obs_a2c,
            )

The following is sample output during training:
time/                 |               |
|    fps                | 73            |
|    iterations         | 24900         |
|    time_elapsed       | 1685          |
|    total_timesteps    | 124500        |
| train/                |               |
|    entropy_loss       | -18.8         |
|    explained_variance | -2.38e-07     |
|    learning_rate      | 0.0007        |
|    n_updates          | 24899         |
|    policy_loss        | -0.00277      |
|    reward             | 4.7075457e-05 |
|    std                | 3.41e+07      |
|    value_loss         | 3.07e-08      |
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
| time/                 |               |
|    fps                | 73            |
|    iterations         | 25000         |
|    time_elapsed       | 1692          |
|    total_timesteps    | 125000        |
| train/                |               |
|    entropy_loss       | -18.8         |
|    explained_variance | 0             |
|    learning_rate      | 0.0007        |
|    n_updates          | 24999         |
|    policy_loss        | 0.00192       |
|    reward             | -5.593601e-05 |
|    std                | 3.65e+07      |
|    value_loss         | 1.28e-08      |
-----------------------------------------
1656.0540571044114
------------------------------------------
| time/                 |                |
|    fps                | 73             |
|    iterations         | 25100          |
|    time_elapsed       | 1698           |
|    total_timesteps    | 125500         |
| train/                |                |
|    entropy_loss       | -18.9          |
|    explained_variance | 0              |
|    learning_rate      | 0.0007         |
|    n_updates          | 25099          |
|    policy_loss        | 0.0236         |
|    reward             | -8.0829945e-05 |
|    std                | 3.91e+07       |
|    value_loss         | 1.82e-06 

The following is output just after the episode is over but there are some leftover timesteps to complete: 
-------------------------------------
| time/                 |           |
|    fps                | 73        |
|    iterations         | 26000     |
|    time_elapsed       | 1763      |
|    total_timesteps    | 130000    |
| train/                |           |
|    entropy_loss       | -19.5     |
|    explained_variance | -2.38e-07 |
|    learning_rate      | 0.0007    |
|    n_updates          | 25999     |
|    policy_loss        | 6.54e-07  |
|    reward             | 0.0       |
|    std                | 7.31e+07  |
|    value_loss         | 1.22e-16  |
-------------------------------------
```

As you can see the model is learning during training: however in DRL_validation, if I use print(action, _states, rewards, dones, info) the function yields output like this: [[-1.]] None [0.] [False] [{}] for every timestep. What are some possible reasons why the model just gives out after an episode?